# Need to update application settings created by another user

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk

A developer who is no longer on the project created the app/appid that our website currently uses to link with Facebook.

I would like to update settings on the app since we have re-branded / changed our domain name and I have no idea how to access it.

Just knowing how to send email to the email contact associated with the app would probably be helpful, but I would also like to know how to move the app from his account to mine.

Answer (score 0):

There's no other option than to get him to add you as an admin for the app.